# Removing deb packages from apt repository with reprepro

Tags: apt, package-management, reprepro

## Problem Summary:

`reprepro list stretch` doesn't list any packages in my apt repository and `reprepro remove stretch <package>` doesn't delete any packages from my repository.  How can I:

1. Add packages so that `reprepro list stretch` finds them, or
2. Use `reprepro` to delete packages from my repo

---

## The Environment:

I have a build machine with an apt repository on it.  When I finish building, I install my package:

```
sudo reprepro -Vb /var/www/html/apt/debian \
              includedeb stretch \
              ${build_dir}/a320-latest-0.0.${SVN_REVISION}-Linux.deb
```

Everything seems to work really well.  I can `apt-get install a320-latest` from any client which has added my repository to their `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

When I inspect further, I can confirm that I have several packages installed:

```
bob@apollo:/var/www/html/apt/debian$ tree pool
pool
└── main
    ├── a
    │   ├── a320
    │   │   └── a320_0.0.571_amd64.deb
    │   └── a320-latest
    │       └── a320-latest_0.0.575_amd64.deb
    ├── h
    │   └── helloworld
    │       └── helloworld_0.2_amd64.deb
    └── s
        ├── sim-dev
        │   └── sim-dev_1.0_amd64.deb
        ├── sim-devenv
        │   └── sim-devenv_1.0_amd64.deb
        ├── sim-runtime
        │   └── sim-runtime_1.1_amd64.deb
        └── sim-workstation
            └── sim-workstation_1.0_amd64.deb

11 directories, 7 files
```

These also seem to be present in the repository registry:

```
bob@apollo:/var/www/html/apt/debian$ cat dists/stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages | grep Package:
Package: a320
Package: a320-latest
Package: helloworld
Package: sim-dev
Package: sim-devenv
Package: sim-runtime
Package: sim-workstation
```

---

## Expected workflow:

I would like to delete `pool/main/a/a320` and `pool/main/h/helloworld`.

I've tried:

```
bob@apollo:/var/www/html/apt/debian$ sudo reprepro list stretch
bob@apollo:/var/www/html/apt/debian$ sudo reprepro remove stretch a320
Not removed as not found: a320
Exporting indices...
```

I expected `reprepro list stretch` would list my packages, and `reprepro remove stretch a320` would remove the a320 package.  But that doesn't seem to do anything.

I was tempted to just delete the `*.deb` files, and the entries in `./dists/.../Packages` manually, but I suspect that this will destroy some checksums and destroy the repository.  It would probably also put `./dists` out of sync with `./db` which contains some binary objects (SQLite?).

I also tried `reprepro export stretch` and `reprepro update stretch` but they didn't seem to do anything.

---

## At least something is working

Everything is great for the client right now.

Also, I can confrm that `reprepro` finds the `stretch` repository, otherwise it would give one of these errors:

```
bob@apollo:/var/www/html/apt$ sudo reprepro list stretch
Error opening config file './conf/distributions': No such file or directory(2)
There have been errors!

bob@apollo:/var/www/html/apt/debian$ sudo reprepro list wheezy
Cannot find definition of distribution 'wheezy'!
There have been errors!
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have part of your solution right there in your question:
you have to tell `reprepo` where to look!

```
sudo reprepro -Vb /var/www/html/apt/debian list stretch
```

and

```
sudo reprepro -Vb /var/www/html/apt/debian remove stretch a320
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Perfect answer thanks!  I assumed that reprepro assumed `-b` was `$(pwd)` if unspecified.  This really cleared things up.

Comment: Glas I was able to help !